# Specify date in ouput file name using python

Tags: python, csv, datetime

My code looks like this

```
import csv
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
month_year = (now.month, now.year)
print(month_year)

outputfilename = 'Filename'+month_year+'.csv'
print(outputfilename)
```

`print(month_year)` gets me my month year

```
(11, 2019)
```

and I would like the date to be in my filename however

```
outputfilename = 'Filename'+month_year+'.csv'
print(outputfilename)
```

gives me the following error

```
    outputfilename = 'Filename'+month_year+'.csv'
TypeError: must be str, not tuple
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:
`month_year = (now.month, now.year)`,
you declared the variable `month_year` as a tuple and not string (as the exception says).

Change the line to this:
`month_year = now.month`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print tuple/list/int+str so you need to convert your `month_year` variable into `string` to be able to use it:

```
month_year = str((now.month, now.year))
```

This would give:

```
'(11, 2019)'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error actually explains it: you can't concatenate string with `tuple` object (monthyear is a tuple here). If you want it to be  as something like `Filename(11, 2019).csv`, you can do it with: `outputfilename = 'Filename' + str(month_year) +'.csv'`.

But there are many nice naming options instead of `Filename(11, 2019).csv`. We can help you if you provide the exact output you want.

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can only use string type with "plus".
So I suggest you to change your code to the following format.

```
import csv
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
month_year = (now.month, now.year)
print(month_year)
outputfilename = 'Filename'+'_'+str(month_year[0])+'_' + str(month_year[1]) + '.csv'
print(outputfilename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this `month_year = str(now.month) +"_" + str(now.year)` and your filename will be `Filename_11_2019.csv`.